# having issues using pg dump

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

i'm trying to use the pg_dump function for a local database using this command:

```
pg_dump -U <enter username> -W -F p <database name> > C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\mcafee_db_backup.sql
```

Every time I try and point to the > C:\Users portion, I get an invalid command error. Please help!

Comment: What if you use the `-f` option to specify the output file?

Comment: @BhartiMohane First, this is invalid syntax. Second, what is the relevant difference to the command in the question?

Comment: Works for me.  Please show the exact error message, that sounds more like a Windows error message than a PostgreSQL one.  Also, maybe the error is hidden behind your `<...>` abstractions.  Please show your un-abstracted command, if it contains nothing secret.

Comment: @jjanes i'm simply getting an error that reads, "invalid command error \Users", but i want to put it on my desktop

Comment: @jjanes the actual full command is... pg_dump -U postgres -W -F p mcafee > C:\Users\usernameommitted\Desktop\mcafee_db_backup.

Comment: Where are you entering this command?  It works for me in a cmd window, and in a Power Shell window.  And what version of Windows are you running?